# ModuleNotFoundError : no module found named <module_name>django

Tags: python, django, runtime-error

I am trying to make a web application using django. so in the `website` folder, I made another app named `U0`.
I made sure to add it in the settings section of the website. but when I try to migrate the `manage.py` file it throws an error saying, No Module found named `U0django`

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new app in Django, you have to use the Django builtin command to create the correct structure of an app for you like this:

> django-admin startapp u0

btw I believe if you want to create it on your own you have to create a file named apps.py in your app folder and add these lines to that to help Django identify it as an app :

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class U0(AppConfig):
    name = 'u0'
```